# Usando temas no fullcalendar

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

Estava vendo uns temas para meu fullcalendar gostei do Bootstrap 4 Litera, gostaria de saber como eu aplico no meu calendário, sei que é por meio do "themeSystem", mas não sei como eu declaro o `<link>`.

Comment: `themeSystem: "bootstrap4"`. Com este código não resulta?

Comment: Não, ele só para de exibir o calendário.

Comment: Veja se tem a versão onde essa é aceite

Comment: Além disso, tem linkado o css do `bootstrap` na tag `<head>`?

Comment: Sim, está tudo certinho.